# MySQL Error when trigger calls a procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers

I have a table (ft_ttd) and want to sort it descending (num) and insert rating numbers into rating column.

[Initial Table http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3922390/2.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3922390/2.png)

Something like that:

[Result Table http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3922390/1.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3922390/1.png)

I've created a procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_ft_ttd_sort  
BEGIN   

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ft_ttd_sort
(id int (2),  
num int (3),  
rating int (2) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY);    

INSERT INTO ft_ttd_sort (id, num)   SELECT id, num FROM ft_ttd ORDER BY num DESC;    
TRUNCATE TABLE ft_ttd;   
INSERT INTO ft_ttd SELECT * FROM ft_ttd_sort;  
DROP TABLE ft_ttd_sort;   
END;
```

When I call it - it works great.

```
CALL proc_ft_ttd_sort;
```

After that I've created trigger calling this procedure.

```
CREATE TRIGGER au_ft_ttd_fer AFTER UPDATE ON ft_ttd FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
CALL proc_ft_ttd_sort(); 
END;
```

Now every time when I update ft_ttd table I've got a error.

```
UPDATE ft_ttd SET num = 9 WHERE id = 3;
ERROR 1422 (HY000): Explicit or implicit commit is not allowed in stored function ortrigger.
```

Any ideas how to make it work?  Maybe this process can be optimized?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Triggers can't do it

DDL aside, your trigger-based approach has a few difficulties.  First, you want to modify the very table that's been updated, and that's [not permitted in MySQL 5](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-program-restrictions.html).

Second, you really want a statement-level trigger rather than FOR EACH ROW — no need to re-rank the whole table for every affected row — but that's [not supported in MySQL 5](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/faqs-triggers.html#qandaitem-B-5-1-3).

#### Dynamically compute `"rating"`

So ... is it enough to just compute `rating` dynamically using a [MySQL ROW_NUMBER() workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql/1895127#1895127)?

```
-- ALTER TABLE ft_ttd DROP COLUMN rating; -- if you like

    SELECT id,
           num,
           @i := @i + 1 AS rating
      FROM ft_ttd
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @i := 0 AS zero) d
  ORDER BY num DESC;
```

Unfortunately, you cannot wrap that SELECT in a VIEW (since a view's [*"SELECT statement cannot refer to system or user variables"*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-view.html)).  However, you could hide that in a selectable stored procedure:

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE sp_ranked_ft_ttd () BEGIN
     SELECT id, num, @i := @i + 1 AS rating
       FROM ft_ttd CROSS JOIN (SELECT @i := 0 AS zero) d
   ORDER BY num DESC
 END
```

#### Or UPDATE if you must

As a kluge, if you must store `rating` in the table rather than compute it, you can run this UPDATE as needed:

```
    UPDATE t
CROSS JOIN (    SELECT id, @i := @i + 1 AS new_rating
                  FROM ft_ttd
            CROSS JOIN (SELECT @i := 0 AS zero) d
              ORDER BY num DESC
           ) ranked
        ON ft_ttd.id = ranked.id SET ft_ttd.rating = ranked.new_rating;
```

Now instruct your client code to ignore rows where `rating IS NULL` — those haven't been ranked yet.  Better, create a VIEW that does that for you.

Kluging further, you can likely regularly UPDATE via [CREATE EVENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-event.html).

Answer (score 2):

The create table statement is an implicit commit, since it's DDL.  Basically, the answer is you can't create a table in a trigger.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-program-restrictions.html

Comment: How can i make this operation otherwise?

Comment: @oleglegun best I can think of is to make the temporary table not temporary.  That would eliminate the DDL from the trigger.

Comment: @oleglegun the truncate table and drop commands are also going to trigger the issue.  You may have to change the design here to something other than a trigger, due to the limitations of MySQL.

Comment: @olegleun what version of MySQL are you using?  You want to at least be on 5.0.17

Comment: mySQL 5.5.9. Thats very awkward that mySQL can't call a procedure out of the trigger(

Comment: @oleglegun I agree, but unfortunately that's the answer.

Comment: @oleglegun, just to be clear, MySQL triggers _can_ call procedures, but there are limitations on what such procedures may do in the context of a trigger.

Comment: @pilcrow Upvoted for clarifying that.  I'm just saying *that* stored procedure doesn't work from the trigger because it involves DDL and other disallowed operations.